# Como resuelvo este error en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

```
10/19 13:36:50: Launching 'app' on Nexus 5 API 24.
App restart successful without requiring a re-install.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.bliss/com.example.bliss.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 4979 on device 'Nexus_5_API_24 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.bliss-1/lib/x86
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 9026(591KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 134MB/134MB, paused 208us total 131.460ms
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x8dc10100, tid 4979
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x8dc10d40, tid 5008
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa0705000: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0705000: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0703230)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.bliss, PID: 4979
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(135613440bytes) bitmap.
        at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
        at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1415)
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:545)
        at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1286)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17071)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16053)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16048)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16048)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16048)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16048)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16048)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16048)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17074)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:751)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16053)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:656)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:662)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:770)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2796)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2604)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2211)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: *trying to draw too large bitmap*. Según el error estás usando una imagen muy pesada. No sé cuál será el tamaño máximo, pero prueba con alguna más pequeña.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: gracias Mateo, eso igual ya me salía cuando me funcionaba y coloqué una más pequeña. Pero este error fatal no creo que esté relacionado con el tamaño de la imagen por que antes me abria en emulador, pero ahora no me abre siquiera

Comment: `.Drawable I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 9026(591KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 134MB/134MB` te pasaste por un mega

Comment: A veces me pasa que, trabajando con el emulador, se sobrecarga o lo que sea y ni siquiera instala la App. Lo que hago en esos casos en borrar la App del dispositivo emulado e instalarla de nuevo. A veces así tampoco funciona y hay que hacer un `Wipe Data` del emulador.